# PHP Curl Get Request Returning False

Tags: php, curl, get

I'm working on something but I do not understand what is happening. I tried different things. I'm sending a get request to website but it's not working, the curl always returns false. But if I put the url to the browser and check it, I got some response. here's the url

```
"https://cleanlead.dlg.co.uk/?circuit=public&fuseaction=lead&Campid=599&Suppid=571&Surveyid=5&Title=Mr&Forename=Adrian&Surname=Reut&Address1=8 Church Road Middlesex&Finance_Insurance_PMI_CurrentlyHave=Yes&Postcode=UB3 2LH&Finance_PMI_ThruCompany=No&TelephoneORMobile=2087976760&Age_Band=30-39"
```

Here' my curl code

```
$ch = curl_init();  
//var_dump($url.$postData);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,urlencode("https://cleanlead.dlg.co.uk/?circuit=public&fuseaction=lead&Campid=599&Suppid=571&Surveyid=5&Title=Mr&Forename=Adrian&Surname=Reut&Address1=8 Church Road Middlesex&Finance_Insurance_PMI_CurrentlyHave=Yes&Postcode=UB3 2LH&Finance_PMI_ThruCompany=No&TelephoneORMobile=2087976760&Age_Band=30-39"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET'); 
$output=curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
var_dump($output);
```

Comment: Don't urlencode the entire URL, only the applicable values.

Comment: So I will remove urlencode?

Comment: HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed If i remove url encode

Comment: That isn't exactly what I said... read the manual on urlencode()...

Comment: put this after the `$output` line. `if ($output === false) curl_error($ch);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `urlencode()` only the value parts of your query string, fields `Postcode` and `Address1` in this case.

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();  
//var_dump($url.$postData);
$requestUrl = "https://cleanlead.dlg.co.uk/?";
$requestUrl .= "circuit=public&fuseaction=lead&Campid=599&Suppid=571&Surveyid=5&Title=Mr&Forename=Adrian&Surname=Reut";
$requestUrl .= "&Address1=" . urlencode("8 Church Road Middlesex");
$requestUrl .= "&Finance_Insurance_PMI_CurrentlyHave=Yes";
$requestUrl .= "&Postcode=" . urlencode("UB3 2LH");
$requestUrl .= "&Finance_PMI_ThruCompany=No&TelephoneORMobile=2087976760&Age_Band=30-39";
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $requestUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET'); 
$output=curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) {
    var_dump();
}
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($output);


?>
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much. This works for me. I just edited the parameters and make it an array instead. I hope I can select the others as answers as well. Thank u